# Can someone check internet usage using MAC Address

Tags: mac-address, sniffing

If I were to briefly connect to a network for like 2 mins would they be able to see everything i've browsed from my home network? If they knew my mac address?

Sounds like a stupid question but am not tech savvy.

Comment: Who is "they" ? The ISP you use, the server you visit, the government, your parents ... ?

Comment: If i connected to a work wifi and they knew my mac address can they see everything from any other network i connected to?

Comment: I'm assuming your talking about vpn and not wifi, unless you physically bring your home network to work... It works both ways, see https://superuser.com/questions/136214/vpn-does-all-traffic-get-routed-through-the-vpn-when-i-am-logged-in .

Comment: Hey randsomus1r, no i mean wifi. If i access the work network can they check data usage from my home network using mac address? So if i was at home on facebook and then come into work the next day, can they see that?

Comment: It really depends on many many factors. Factor 1: Why and who? If your workplace wanted to monitor employee at home, why would they do that ? Factor 2: resources. Is it probable your company would waste resources on monitoring employee home network. Factor 3: Do you bring any data from work home. If you do, why ? As for technical aspects, yes, it is possible.

Comment: How can they do that when my home network is completely different isp etc? Just out of curiosity? How can say a facebook page i visited the night before outside of their network page be tracked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, but the answer is generally NO.

First, I will pinpoint your question (as it follow from comments):

> I use my laptop both at home and at work. In both cases I connect to to the network (and - possibly to the Internet) by its WiFi adapter, so in both networks I have the same MAC address.
>
> Is it possible for my employer to use my connection to the business network to obtain info about my previous activities within my home network?

If you have *no publicly shared folders* and your employer don't employ *(illegal) sophisticated hacker activities* to obtain access to your computer, the answer is NO.

It is your computer and you control, whom, when, and how will be allowed the access to the (part) of your stored data (including your browser history).

Comment: Yeh that was pretty much what I was asking! Your answer doesn't shock or suprise me in the sense that it can be achieved. It's good to know thanks for answering. :)